# Why are Fremen children not all pre-born with prescience?

Tags: dune

In the *Dune* saga (1st three books) why aren't Fremen children born with prescience or pre-born? I get that Chani was put on a high spice diet when pregnant but surely given that all adult Fremen have the blue eyes and participate in the Spice orgy their systems would be so laced with Melange that it would transfer to their unborn children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becoming a Reverend Mother requires the Bene Gesserit sister to take and change the bile of a dying sandworm into the [Water of Life](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Water_of_Life) using her prana-bindu training<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> (literally creating a molecular catalyst out of individual molecules). During that process, if the mother is pregnant, her child may also gain the ability to access those same genetic memories *but without the complex Bene Gesserit mental training that allows them to selectively control those memories*.

**In the absence of a *revelatory moment* (the moment in which a neophyte Bene Gesserit become a full Reverend Mother), merely taking large amounts of Spice isn't sufficient to awaken genetic memory in the children of any pregnant Fremen women**<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>.

---

The [Dune Encyclopedia](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dune_Encyclopedia) makes the steps required abundantly clear

> *The Azhar Book outlines the conditions necessary to a state of
>   possession (Mahrana IV: H-K). **First a pregnant Bene Gesserit breeder
>   must ingest the Water of Life, apparently an hallucinogenic chemical
>   which varied during the history of the order. This chemical, carried
>   in her blood to the womb, activates the fetal psychic awareness and
>   produces a babble of sound and sensory imagery which the un-born is
>   unable to comprehend or assimilate. At birth, this "awakened" baby
>   supposedly sees with adult com- prehension because of the active,
>   intelligent, adult memories it now carries at a conscious level.** The
>   child, therefore, appears to the uninitiated as extremely precocious
>   but to the knowledgeable as a possible Abomination. Only bright Bene
>   Gesserit children were suspect; precocious lay children were safe from
>   scrutiny.*

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup><sup><sub>Jessica mentions that the process of becoming a Reverend Mother at the Chapter House uses a different method (albeit one that also uses spice) but is basically the same in outcome</sub></sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup></sup><sub><sup>Note that Leto and Ghanima are also pre-born, but **through their genetic inheritance from Paul** and hence can be discounted from this discussion.</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info, I haven't read passed 'God Emperor' yet. Was wondering as Fremen have a test of possession that it was a more regular occurrence?

Comment: @SeamusTheDog - Hmm. Good question, My gut instinct is that it's a more general test for madness/dementia. It apparently involves overdosing the individual on Spice to see if they're actually possessed.

Comment: Like what was done to Leto II? Surely that would enduce the genetic memories even if one was not mad or possessed therefore forcing it?

Comment: @SeamusTheDog - Without Bene Gesserit training, high doses of Melange are just poisonous. You might get some slight prescience/genetic memory stuff happening if you skirt the line, but more than likely you'll just die.

Comment: Even Fremen who have for generations been exposed to more spice than anyone except navigators or Reverend Mothers?

Comment: @SeamusTheDog - Consuming spice isn't what makes a mother give birth to a pre-born. Consuming the water of life (or some similar torment) is what does it.

Comment: What about the twins then?

Comment: @SeamusTheDog - They're pre-born as a result of their *genetic inheritance* as well as Chani's heroic consumption of spice.. If we take the Encyclopedia as canon, her children were mildly prescient, but not pre-born themselves.

Comment: Wow, I really need to read more!! Thanks Val

Comment: @Valorum but Dune Messiah and Children of Dune indicate otherwise - for one, Leto II is able to "lend" Paul his vision and communicate with his father almost right after being born. And Leto and Ghanima tap their Other Memory before Leto is overdosed with spice.

Comment: @HorusKol - That's my point. Pre-born means able to access these memories from birth but it's not an inheritable condition.

Comment: @Valorum - sorry, I misread the first sentence in your comment where you say they are pre-born... I was countering the point from the Encyclopaedia

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Dune Encyclopedia isn't canon. A lot of the articles in it contradict the later books by Kevin J. Anderson. For what it's worth, I do like the Encyclopedia version of e.g. the Butlerian Jihad better than the one in the Anderson books.

Comment: @KlausÆMogensen - As I've said before, it became progressively less canonical with each edition. Canon (ish) to begin with and then finally decanonised by Herbert's talentless offspring.

Comment: So was the 1st Leto II pre-born or is this a different question?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - That's a different question. He doesn't appear to be, largely because his mother wasn't chucking down spice when she had him.

Comment: Is there much known about the first Leto II? It's such a throw away part of book 1 it's almost not worth mentioning. Should I ask is as a new question?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Very little is known about him beyond what's mentioned in the book. He barely merits a passing mention in the Encyclopedia. There's a glancing reference to him in Heretics of Dune, but zero mention of any of the special abilities you'd expect from a pre-born child

Comment: @Valorum - seems odd? Thank for the info, not long finished God Emperor so will move on soon.

Answer (score -1):

Ingesting the water of life isn’t necessarily related to becoming a reverbs mother.  It’s poisonous nature causes the candidate to go into crisis and either transform into a being with powers of reverend mother.  Being a reverend mother isn’t necessary for the awakening, besides the training and preparation.

I haven’t heard an explanation of Leto and Ghana’s status of pre-born.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm afraid the 'Your Answer' field is only meant for posting answers to the question at the top of the thread though, not for responding to previous answers. In order to respond to previous answers the right way, you need to earn a bit more reputation to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] center to learn more.

Comment: It seems you now have enough rep to comment.  Welcome to SF&F!